# Landscape orientation and page centring in seminar class

Tags: presentations

I am trying to get a grip on the basics of the seminar document class to write presentations (I would usually use Beamer but don't have the choice in this case). All I really need is for the document to be landscape-orientated with the content of each page centred and taking up the available page space. My attempts result in the content of each page being located in the top left-hand corner of the page and with most of the page white space.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{seminar}
\slideframe{oval}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah.

\begin{slide}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since posting this question I have found a solution by adapting a suggestion made (thanks to Joel) at https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/jff/Beamer/pdflatex-and-seminar.html. For landscape orientation use the preamble

```
\documentclass[a4,landscpae]{seminar}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfpagewidth=11.69 truein % A4 portrait
\pdfpageheight=8.27 truein % A4 portrait
\pdfhorigin=1truein     % default value(?), but doesn't work without
\pdfvorigin=1truein     % default value(?), but doesn't work without
\slideheight=17.5cm
\slidewidth=23cm
```